# How to copy the string which has termination characters into another string in C?

Tags: c, string, memory

I have the string like this

```
    char year_cp[5], mon_cp[3], date_cp[3];

    char *src;
    src = "2017-05-30";
```

I want to store year, month, date in separate buffers. I tried the strncpy() and sprintf() also. Like this

```
    strncpy(mon_cp,&src[4],2); //strncpy(mon_cp, src+4, 3);
    mon_cp[2] = '\0';
    printf("mon-cp %s\n",mon_cp);
    strncpy(year_cp,&src[0],4); //strncpy(year_cp, src+0, 5);
    year_cp[4] = '\0';
    printf("year-cp %s\n",year_cp);
```

Even I pass the the src string as

```
    src = "20170530";
```

It is copying only mon_cp, not copying the year into year_cp

I got the segmentation fault.

Please tell me the best way to achieve this

Comment: You have to make sure there is always a NUL character '\0' on the end of strings in C.  All of the str* functions in C have cases where they fail to give a useful result.

Comment: At `strncpy(mon_cp,&src[4],2)` the index of the first month character is not `src[4]` but `src[5]` based in the earlier definition `src = "2017-05-30";`. But is does align with the later definition `src = "20170530";`. So voting to close as the question requires MCVE.

Comment: The posted code looks OK. The problem is in other parts of code. Please make a [mcve] - this will either make the question answerable or eliminate the problem altogether.

Comment: strtok is what you are looking for

Comment: will it make any difference if I use char array instead of char pointer? @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `sscanf()`, like so:

```
char * src = "2017-05-30";
unsigned year, month, day;
if(sscanf(src, "%u-%u-%u", &year, &month, &day) < 3) {
    /* ERROR */
}
```

If for some reason you need the components as strings, just using `%s` won't work for you: you will need to convert back with `snprintf()` calls or the like.

Comment: What if I have the string without "-" or "/" ?

Comment: @emb-pro If you want the string to be parsed be multiple formats, then you need have your code figure out which format was used and parse accordingly. Learn to use `regex(3)` functions like `regcomp` and `regexec` and you will be able to parse _YYYYMMDD_, _YYYY/MM/DD_, and _YYYY-MM-DD_ without needing to check if the string contains the separators or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use strtok and a counter.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

char s[11];
scanf("%s",s);
char token[2]="-";
int count=0;
char year[5],month[3],day[3];
char *split;
split=strtok(s,token);
while(split!=NULL){
    if(count==0){
    strcpy(year,split);
    }
    else if(count==1){
    strcpy(month,split);
    }
    else{
    strcpy(day,split);
    }
    split=strtok(NULL,token);
    count++;
}

printf("\n%s",month);
return 0;

}
```

Note that here I have assumed your input to be a constant format. "2017-05-30". YYYY-MM-DD

Also note that the OP has a slight mistake in strncpy for year... He is using wrong array. It is not str_cp but year_cp.

Comment: This code will malfunction in the year 10000 (not that anyone should be worried about that)

Answer (score 1):

You access your arrays out of bounds.

```
char year_cp[5], mon_cp[3], date_cp[3];
```

...

```
mon_cp[3] = '\0';
```

If `mon_cp` is an array with three elements, you can't set the fourth element to zero.

Since `mon_cp[0]` is the first element, `mon_cp[1]` is the second element. Thus `mon_cp[2]` is the third element and `mon_cp[3]` is the fourth element.

If you need an array with a fourth element, you need to create an array with four elements!

Answer (score 0):

More of example of using regcomp and regexec which will parse both *20170530* or *2017-05-30*. Just strcpy from tmpvalue to year_cp, mon_cp, or date_cp when i equals 1, 2, 3 respectively.

```
/*
 * parsedate.c
 * vi: set ts=4 sw=4 ic:  
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char    *argv[];
{
    /* nummatch is 4, Entire string and YYYY MM DD */
    int         nummatch=4;
    char        year_cp[5], mon_cp[3], date_cp[3];
    regex_t     dateregx;
    regmatch_t  pmatch[nummatch];
    int         i, rv;
    const char* pattern = "^([[:digit:]]{4})[^[:digit:]]?([[:digit:]]{2})[^[:digit:]]?([[:digit:]]{2})";
    char    dateline[80] = "2017-05/29";
    char        tmpvalue[256];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    if( regcomp( &dateregx, pattern, REG_EXTENDED ) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pattern failed to compile.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Execute regular expression */
    if( regexec( &dateregx, dateline, nummatch, pmatch, 0 ) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dateline <%s> does not match pattern <%s>\n",
        dateline, pattern );
        return -1;
    }

    /* Print values */
    for( i = 0; i < nummatch && pmatch[i].rm_so != -1; i++ ) {
        memset(tmpvalue, 0, 256 );
        strncpy( tmpvalue, &dateline[pmatch[i].rm_so], pmatch[i].rm_eo-pmatch[i].rm_so);
        printf("matched pmatch[%d].rm_so: %d    pmatch[%d].rm_eo: %d  -   \"%s\"\n", i, (int)pmatch[i].rm_so, i, (int)pmatch[i].rm_eo, tmpvalue);
        if ( i == 1 ) {
            strcpy( year_cp, tmpvalue );
        } else if ( i == 2 ) {
            strcpy( mon_cp, tmpvalue );
        } else if ( i == 3 ) {
            strcpy( date_cp, tmpvalue );
        }
    }

    printf( "Year: %s\tMonth: %s\tDay: %s\n", year_cp, mon_cp, date_cp );
    return 0;

}
```